# How to pass a local access table as parameter to SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, parameter-passing, stored-functions

I am modifying an access 2010 application so that it uses SQL server to run its queries. The data has been transferred to the server some times ago, and used as linked tables, but that proves a bit slow and non-optimal. So I'm trying to put the queries on the server.

I have no problem for simple queries, views,... and I'm using stored functions when there is a need for simple parameters (dates, ids,...).

But now I have a process in that application that selects a bunch of ids in the database, stores them in a local table, does a bunch of actions on them (report with sub report, print preview, print, update of the original records with the date of print when the user confirms that everything printed OK), and empties the local table if all actions succeed.

I can't simply use an SQL server table to store the ids since many people use the application at the same time, and the same table is used in several processes; I can't use temporary tables since they disappear as soon as access goes to the next action; and I can't find a way to use a local table as a parameter to server stored procedures. Basically I'm stuck.

Can anyone help? Is there a way to do that (pass a bunch of values as a table to a server stored function)? Or another process that would achieve the same result (have a table on the server specific to the current user, or a general table and somehow identify the lines belonging to current user, or anything else)?

Comment: check this question if it will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52014608/how-to-pass-table-valued-parameters-into-stored-procedure-from-excel-vba

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 methods that I use. Both work very well for multi-user apps. Here are the basics. You'll need to work out the details.

1. Create a table (tblSessions) in SQL Server with an identity column SessID (INT NOT NULL).
   Create a function in Access to generate and retrieve a new SessID.
   Create a second SS table tblWork with 2 columns SessID, YourID. Add appropriate indexes and keys. Link this table to your Access app. Then instead of inserting the IDs for your query into an Access temp table, insert them into tblWork along with a new SessID. You can now join tblWork to other SS tables/views to use as the datasource for you reports. Be sure to add the SessID that you generated to your where clause.
2. Create a stored procedure to generate the data for your reports. Include a parameter @YourIDList VARCHAR(MAX). Call the proc via a passthrough queryand pass the list of your IDs as a comma (or whatever you prefer) separated string to @YourIDList. In the proc, split @YourIDList into a temp table. SS2016+ has a STRING_SPLIT function. For older versions, roll your own. There are plenty of examples available. Then join the temp table to the other tables you need to generate your output. Use the PT query as your report datasource, or dump it into an Access temp table and use that as you report datasource.