# Pass record set from Access VBA as SQL Server stored procedure user-defined table type parameter

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

In C# you can pass data table as a user-defined table type as a SQL Server parameter. Is this possible with MS Access VBA, too? Can I pass `adodb.recordset` as such a stored procedure parameter?

I tried to use the following code (which already works for me with all other data types), but I got an error when I'm trying to pass record set, if some one can help with code I'd appreciate it.

```
If ServerConOpen = False Then
    DoCmd.CancelEvent
    Exit Sub
End If
Dim cmd    As New adodb.Command
Dim rs     As New adodb.Recordset
rs.Open "CustData", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnx
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "CustDtaInsert"
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@UserDefineTable", adUserDefined, adParamInput, , rs)
cmd.Execute
ServerConClose
```

I get the following error on this line

```
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@UserDefineTable", adUserDefined, adParamInput, , rs)
```

[image]

Comment: I would have tried adVariant except MS docs states does not support ADO https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/datatypeenum. I think answer to your question is "no".

Comment: What about creating the parameter first and then try to append it?

Comment: i think that sql server parameter can accept data table only not adodb.recordset

Answer (score 1):

VBA and SQL Server do not share any common constructs to pass table data so it cannot be directly achieved. It could be done by writing data to a linked table in Access but that is not an elegant solution.

The only way around it would be to pass the data to the Stored procedure in a text format such as JSON or XML and populate a table on the server. This technique was explained at length in a [previous StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52014608/how-to-pass-table-valued-parameters-into-stored-procedure-from-excel-vba).

Comment: OK I got it , but i need a real effective solution , because i need to send multiple tables data to Sql Server first , then server will validate data after check with stored procedure , then server insert data without any errors, i found XML Files effective with API , but not with normal daily data entry

Comment: Unfortunately there aren't any really great solutions. A linked table would probably be the easiest but performance will be terrible if there is a lot of data. Another way would be to loop though a recordset and send the records one at a time to a table on the server using an insert command. Use command parameters rather than dynamic sql for the best performance but it still won't be great.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain this will work, but you could try replacing the line raising the error with the following.

```
set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@UserDefineTable", adUserDefined, adParamInput, , rs)
cmd.Parameters.Append prm
```

First declare it of course. `Dim prm as ADODB.Parameter`

Comment: I tried but still same error , i need a way to send my multiple data to sql server and let the server validate and insert data